# What would a Chrome Extension be delayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My current Chrome extension is always delayed in responding. I always have to turn it on twice before it can work. Why would this be the case?

**Background Script:**

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "turnon.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"on.js"});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "turnoff.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"off.js"});
  }
});
```

**Injected HTML Code:**

```
var jqlib = document.createElement('script');
jqlib.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
jqlib.id= 'jqlibjs';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqlib);


var jqlib2 = document.createElement('script');
jqlib2.type = 'text/javascript';
jqlib2.id = 'jqlib2';    
document.head.appendChild(jqlib2);   
document.getElementById('jqlib2').innerHTML = "$('body').on('click', function(){$(this).hide();});";
```

Comment: Why do you inject jQuery into the page instead of using it in your content script? What is the actual goal of the extension?

Comment: The goal is to hide a specific html element on any page when the user clicks something specific like the body of the page.

Comment: It works only on second click because loading jquery from external server takes time, whereas the second script is executed immediately. You can "fix" it by creating the second script in `onload` callback of the first one, but your approach is basically incorrect. You don't need jquery, you don't need to insert scripts into the page. You can do everything in a content script without jQuery in a couple of lines.

Comment: Why do you insert jQuery (30kiB of minimized code) to save yourself at most a couple hundred characters of JavaScript?